# Where has the Khajiit Caravan gone?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Before I did the stormcloaks/imperials quests a Khajiit caravan was located outside of Whiterun. After these quests, they are no longer there, do they ever come back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! (And note that their presence has no direct relation to the Civil War quest lines.)

There are three groups of Khajiit traders that travel between the cities of Skyrim. You'll have encountered Ri'saad's band outside Whiterun, and may find him again near Markarth; the others (led by Ahkari and Ma'dran) can be found between Riften and Dawnstar, and between Windhelm and Solitude, respectively. They'll set up camp by a city for a few days, then move on to the other.

Ahkari is notable as one of his crew, Kharjo, offers a radiant quest and can be recruited as a follower upon its completion. Additionally, if you're interested in the Thieves' Guild, a quest chain obtained via the guild's 'additional job' quests can unlock fences within all of the Khajiit caravans.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Khajiit_Traders), and [summary](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Khajiit_Caravan_%28Skyrim%29) (thanks Trent Hawkins)

Comment: I'll just add the [Elderscrolls Wikia page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Khajiit_Caravan_%28Skyrim%29) on the caravans here in the comments.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Thanks, that's actually a better summary than UESP - I'll edit that into my answer. :)

Comment: No problem, which of the two wikis has more/better information is sometimes a crapshoot.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Khajit aren't simply at one or the other.  They actually travel by foot between their destinations.  I've never seen them departing or arriving, but I've seen them on a path in the middle of nowhere headed toward on of their spots.

Comment: @nhgrif Agreed, I've spotted that too - I once handed in Kharjo's quest while he was on the road. I assume the game determines whether they're stationed or moving, based on time, when you arrive at the city cell.

Comment: thank you all for the great suggestions! I've studied all of your answers and I'm pleased with them, couldn't ask for better answers! :-)